# Mathematics of the birthday attack

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, reference-request, birthday

Let $X, Y$ be finite sets with $|Y|= n$ and $f: X \to Y$ such that all preimages $f^{-1}(y),\,y\in Y$ have the same cardinality.

A pair $x_1 \neq x_2$ in $X$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ is called a *collision*.  The literature on the birthday attack states (cf. [wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack)). :

> **(S)** If $f$ is evaluated at   $\sqrt{2log(2)}\cdot \sqrt{n}$ elements than the probability of observing a collision is 1/2 for $n$ large.

The argument that is usually given is simple: Computing $y=f(x)$ for randomly chosen $x$ is the same as choosing $y \in Y$ randomly. This is equivalent to drawing balls from an urn containing $n$ labelled balls with replacement. So the problem is solved by the birthday problem.

But actually, I think this argument isn't very convincing. For, suppose  $f$ is bijective. Then there will be no collision at all and the statement is wrong.

In some sources (e.g. [www.pumj.org/docs/Issue1/Article_3.pdf](http://www.pumj.org/docs/Issue1/Article_3.pdf)) $|X| \gg |Y|$ is required. But then, in a proof, this property has to be used seriously – just referring to the birthday problem for $Y$ isn't sufficient.

**Question:** Is there a precise proof of the statement (S) in the literature or can someone sketch such a proof?

Comment: First of all, cryptographic hash functions are never bijective since the domain of a hash function is always infinite while the range is finite. Furthermore, the probability that a randomly selected function $f$ is bijective or even injective is negligible.

Comment: You do not need for the domain to be infinite since you can simply let $f$ be a random function (and hash functions are supposed to be random).

Comment: @Joseph Van Name: You can interpret the question as follows: Does (S) hold for functions defined in the question (preimages of singletons have same cardinality) if $|X| \gg |Y|$ ? I believe this is a nontrivial problem.

Comment: $f$ needs to be a random function. By the way, this question is not appropriate for MO.

Comment: @Joseph Van Name: Why need $f$ to be a random function for (S) to hold if $|X| \gg |Y|$ ? Do you have an example of a non-random function with preimages of same cardinality and $|X| \gg |Y|$ such that (S) doesn't hold ?

Comment: The point is: Let $|X|/|Y|=m$. The probability for observing a collision after evaluating $k$ randomly chosen elements from $X$ is $$p= 1 - \binom{n}{k}m/\binom{nm}{k}$$. So the question depends only on $n, m$ and no futher properties of $f$, in contrast to your assumption that $f$ has to be random. That's also the reason why I believe the question is appropriate for MO.

Comment: No. The question is not appropriate for MO. And you're calculation is incorrect since the probability of finding a collision does depend on the properties of $f$. I do not know why people are upvoting this question.

Comment: @Joseph Van Name: Sorry, my calculation does depend on the property of $f$: Take m=1 (i.e. f is bijective). Than p=0 as expected. Why do you think the calculation isn't correct ?

Comment: That should be $$p = 1 - \dfrac{{n \choose k} m^k}{{nm \choose k}}$$  i.e. for an instance with no collision you choose $k$ distinct members of $Y$  and then for each of them you choose one of its $m$ inverse images under $f$.

Comment: There are really **no** other properties of $f$ once you specify that $|Y|=n$ and $|f^{-1}(y)| = m$ for all $y$: any two such functions are equivalent up to permutations of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: @Robert Israel: Thanks! The missing power was the problem. Now the proof follows from your formula.

Comment: @Joseph Van Name: Would you please remove your comments since they didn't address the question and just clutter the post. Thanks.

Comment: user120513. No.

Comment: @ Joseph Van Name: Let me explain why your comments aren't helpful and are, in fact, of erroneous content: The question is concerned with the probability of a collision of a surjective function. --- You inaccurately stated  (1) function has to be cryptographic hash function (2) domain has to be infinite (3)  $f$ needs to be random. --- As can be seen by Robert Israel's comment and the answer nothing of what you wrote is true and necessary to comupte the asymptotic probability of a collision. --- Having this explained, I hope you will remove your useless/erroneous comments. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scatch of the proof for (S): As explained by Robert Israel in a comment, the probability for a collision after evaluating $k$ elements from $X$ is 
$$p = 1 - \dfrac{{n \choose k} m^k}{{nm \choose k}}\tag{1}$$
Let $q(n) := (n-k+1)\cdots n / n^k$. By the standard approximation $q(n)\sim e^{\frac{-k(k-1)}{2n}}$ (e.g. [Is there a precise error bound for the approximation used in the description of the Birthday Paradox distribution?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280221/is-there-a-precise-error-bound-for-the-approximation-used-in-the-description-of/280225#280225)) we find for $p' := 1-p$ and $n$ large: 
$$p' = \frac{q(n)n^km^k}{q(nm)(nm)^k} \sim \frac{e^{\frac{-k(k-1)}{2n}}}{e^{\frac{-k(k-1)}{2nm}}}=e^{(\frac{1}{m}-1)\frac{k(k-1)}{2n}}$$
Taking $k=\sqrt{n}$ yields $p' \sim e^{\frac{1}{2}\cdot(\frac{1}{m}-1)}\sim e^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ for $m$ large. This proves (S).